# Robin Fairbairns died on 25 February

Tags: ctan

Here is some sad news, communicated to the members of UK TUG by Joseph Wright.

> I am sad to say that Robin Fairbairns, former UK-TUG Chair and
> long-standing CTAN node maintainer, died late last month. Robin was
> well-known to many of us, either in his CTAN role, as author and
> editors of the UK TeX FAQ or as a constant presence on comp.text.tex.
> Robin was also a member of the LaTeX Project, and author of several
> important LaTeX packages. His funeral will take place on the 30th
> March at Cambridge Crematorium:
>
> https://funeral-notices.co.uk/notice/fairbairns/5024136

On hearing this I shared with the members of UK TUG this message.

> I'm saddened to hear that Robin Fairbairns has died. I knew that for
> some time he had health problems. His family, friends and colleagues
> have my condolences.
>
> About 30 years ago I learnt of his role in the TeX community, and was
> delighted that he and I lived close to each other in Cambridge. I
> learnt a lot from him, particularly working together in person on the
> TeX FAQ, which had recently become the responsibility of the UK TeX
> Users Group.
>
> In 1994 Chris Rowley, as chair of UK TUG, reported
>
> *The notable innovation in 1994 has been the regular appearance of
> Baskerville. Under the editorship of Sebastian Rahtz, and with Robin
> Fairbairns and Jonathan Fine as publisher and distributor, issues of
> our newsletter now reach members approximately every two months.*
>
> *It contains an interesting variety of TeX-related articles in addition
> to notices of meetings and subscription forms. In my opinion,
> Baskerville is the best in content and, by a wide margin, in
> timeliness of all the journals and newsletters produced by TeX user
> groups.*
>
> *Thanks to Sebastian, Robin and Jonathan, and also to all those who
> have written items for Baskerville.*
>
> Chris's message is at http://uk.tug.org/wp-installed-content/uploads/2008/12/51.pdf (p35)
>
> With the tragic early death of Sebastian in 2016, and Robin this year,
> of the four persons named in that news story only myself and Chris
> Rowley are still alive.

- https://tug.org/pipermail/uktug-announce/2022q1/000611.html #
  Joseph's message
- https://tug.org/pipermail/uktug-announce/2022q1/000612.html #
  Jonathan's message

with a mixture of sadness, regrets and gratitude

Jonathan

Comment: Sad news... Rip...

Comment: Whilst I really do appreciate the reason you've posted this, it's not a question (and it's not about TeX in a technical sense): I'm afraid it likely be closed

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question.

Comment: There's not really a good way to communicate announcements with the tex.se community (the chat is ephemeral and the meta obscure).

Comment: Robin was a stalwart to the TeX Community. I always enjoyed my interactions with him, though they were quite some time ago.

Comment: @DonHosek This was communicated in the chat, and the message was "highlighted" and upvoted by many people there, and has been visible there for many days. I think it disappeared first today.

Comment: scifi.sx has [RIP notices in the meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=RIP); it seems to work quite well there.